# Paypal Chained Payment for mobile web

Tags: cordova, paypal, ionic-framework, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I used Chained Payment into the PhoneGap project.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/

```
    payment.executeCall()
    .success(function(payKey, response) {
        $scope.adaptive.payKey = payKey;
        var options = {
            location: 'no',
            clearcache: 'yes',
            toolbar: 'yes'
        };

        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(
            'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&expType=mini&paykey='+payKey,
            '_blank', options)
        .then(function(event) {

        })
        .catch(function(event) {
        });

    })
    .error(function(error){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
```

As you can see above code, I made paypal transaction as first, and then open the url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&expType=mini&paykey='+payKey to Redirect the Customer to PayPal for Authorization.
But Paypal shows me bigger page than mobile screen. It seems to be desktop version.

Here is screenshot : https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/563845ccd9d583d1d801d7f8/576x1024/c2f094ba36e9089441dd3476ffd9226d/photo.jpg

I tried this answer. [Paypal Adaptive payment for mobile web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463389/paypal-adaptive-payment-for-mobile-web) But the result was same.

How can I get mobile version of Paypal page?
Please advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive payments on mobile are supported as a embedded layout.
You can refer to this documentation .

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_adaptivepaymentsmobile.pdf