# javascript: window.open does not work?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-chrome, webview

i am trying to implement this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30225669/533426

but, a simple open window does not work, see here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkLNaX

javascript:

```
 window.open('http://www.bippo.com', '_blank');
alert("wtf");
```

am i missing something?

this should work especially well on android and iphone phones.

Comment: General rule in browsers is it requires a user event to be able to open a new window due to abuse/security. Also depends on user security settings ... some might see a prompt...others see nothing if you try to open without user event

Comment: See the correct answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set) same idea.

Comment: even if manually triggering it, it won't work: see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkLNaX

Comment: In your script there are several undefined variables (top, left...). It can't work if you don't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you redefined the open function elsewhere or *window.open()* isn't called directly by a user action. Specially in mobile browsers, you can't call this function from a timer or any asynchronous task.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>

function test(){
    window.open("http://www.bippo.com",'_blank');
    alert("wtf");  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your codepen code work, just check your browser popup block.

```
window.open("http://www.bippo.com",'_blank');
```

Comment: the error message is this: `pen.js:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://s.codepen.io" from accessing a frame with origin "http://codepen.io". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`